# ER diagram maker (editor) like PonyOrm editor

Tags: erd, ponyorm

I try to build the ER diagram maker like [PonyOrm Editor](https://editor.ponyorm.com/user/pony/PhotoSharing). Is there any open source project or source code available for the same.

Any Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/ondras/wwwsqldesigner) we can find similar plugin